# Line break in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, newline, iif

I'm having trouble adding a line break in SSRS 2008.

I've tried all of these different ways but nothing is doing it.

`"+ chr(10) +" , "& chr(10) &" , "& chr(13) & chr(10) &" , "& vbcrlf &" , "+ vbcrlf +" , "Environment.NewLine"`

Here's my `textbox` expression:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!VCHTYPE.Value, "Dataset1")="C","This is a huge paragrpah of text." +
vbcrlf + "separated by line feeds at each paragraph." +
vbcrlf + vbcrlf + "I want to separate the paragraphs." +
vbcrlf + vbcrlf + "Its not working though."
, "This is the second huge paragraph of text." +
vbcrlf + "separated by line feeds at each paragraph." +
vbcrlf + vbcrlf + "I want to separate the paragraphs." +
vbcrlf + vbcrlf + "Its not working though." )
```

Comment: It works for me. Check your Error List when you preview it. Also just to rule it out, try replacing the VCHTYPE value with "C".

Answer (score 95):

Use`Environment.NewLine` instead of vbcrlf

Comment: Can you elaborate on why to use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `vbcrlf`? What are the benefits of the one over the other, or why not use `vbcrlf`?

Comment: As a note on this (as covered by Samrat Sarang and krilovich answer below), if your placeholder is set to HTML then you will need to use '<br />' as newline / vbcrlf will not work.

Comment: If RDL Sandboxing is enabled you cannot use `Environment.NewLine`, you won't be able to publish the report. `VbCrLf` is the way to go in that scenario.

Answer (score 24):

If your placeholder is in html enabled mode then `"<br />"` will work as a newline

Comment: As a note on this (as covered by Samrat Sarang answer below), this is the only way to do newline if your placeholder is set to HTML.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

(In Visual Studio)

1. Open the .rdl file in Designer (right-click on file in Solution
   Explorer > View Designer)
2. Right-click on the Textbox you are working with, choose Expression
3. In the `Set expression for: Value` box enter your expression like:

   ```
   ="first line of text. Param1 value: " & Parameters!Param1.Value & Environment.NewLine() 
   & "second line of text. Field value: " & Fields!Field1.Value & Environment.NewLine() 
   & "third line of text."
   ```

Answer (score 10):

In Order to implement Line Break in SSRS, there are 2 ways

1. **Setting HTML Markup Type** 
   Update the Markup Type of the placeholder to HTML and then make use of `<br/>` tag to introduce line break within the expression

`="first line of text. Param1 value: " & Parameters!Param1.Value & "<br/>" & Parameters!Param1.Value`

2. **Using Newline function** 
   Make use of Environment.NewLine() function to add line break within the expression.

`="first line of text. Param1 value: " & Parameters!Param1.Value & Environment.NewLine()
 & Parameters!Param1.Value`

***Note:-*** Always remember to leave a space after every "&" *(ampersand)* in order to evaluate the expression properly

Answer (score 8):

You should NOT quote your Environment.NewLine man. Try `"Your Text" & Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `vbcrlf` for new line in SSSR. e.g.

```
= First(Fields!SAPName.Value, "DataSet1") & vbcrlf & First(Fields!SAPStreet.Value, "DataSet1") & vbcrlf & First(Fields!SAPCityPostal.Value, "DataSet1") & vbcrlf & First(Fields!SAPCountry.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Answer (score 4):

I've always had luck with the Chr(10) & Chr(13) - I have provided a sample below.  This is an expression for an address text box I have in a report.

```
=Iif(Fields!GUAR_STREET_2.Value <> "",Fields!GUAR_STREET.Value & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & LTrim(Fields!GUAR_STREET_2.Value),Fields!GUAR_STREET.Value)
```

Also, if you are building a string you need to concatenate stuff together with an & not a +  Here is what I think your example should look like

```
    =IIF(First(Fields!VCHTYPE.Value, "Dataset1")="C","This is a huge paragrpah of text." &
Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "separated by line feeds at each paragraph." &
Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "I want to separate the paragraphs." &
Chr(10) & Chr(13) &  Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "Its not working though."
, "This is the second huge paragraph of text." &
Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "separated by line feeds at each paragraph." &
Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "I want to separate the paragraphs." &
Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "Its not working though." )
```

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't working for me either.  vbcrlf and Environment.Newline() both had no effect.  My problem was that the Placeholder Properties had a Markup type of HTML.  When I changed it to None, it worked like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This One

```
="Line 1" & "<br>" & "Line 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Environment.NewLine was working fine while previewing the report in Visual Studio.  But when I tried to publish the rdl to Dynamics 365 CE, I received the error "The report server has RDLSandboxing enabled and the Value expression for the text box 'Textbox10' contains a reference to a type, namespace, or member 'Environment' that is not allowed."

So I had to replace Environment.NewLine with vbcrlf.